# How to create 3D geometry for a custom mesh

Tags: 3d, three.js, mesh, face

I created a custom mesh. That works so far.
Regarding to the face creation I realized it by a switch operation.
If I have 4 Vertices (0,1,2),(0,2,3) and so on...

```
   switch (coordinates_updated.vertices.length) {

        case 5://wall
            geometry.faces.push(
                new THREE.Face3(0, 1, 2),
                new THREE.Face3(0, 2, 3));
            break;
        case 6:
            geometry.faces.push(
                new THREE.Face3(0, 1, 2),// make a triangle
                new THREE.Face3(0, 2, 3),
                new THREE.Face3(0, 3, 4));
            break;
        ...
```

But now some error occurs for more complex buildings! See the image [building](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOVYT.jpg)
My problem is I have for each building different numbers of vertices. 
I need a kind of method that can create the faces automatically ( no switch operation) and without overlaps.

can anyone give some advice or tips how to do this.
Are there some methods wich are handle this kind of problem???

Comment: See http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_geometry_shapes.html

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to achieve is known as 'Polygon Triangulation'. [Here](http://www.cs.unc.edu/~dm/CODE/GEM/chapter.html) is an overview over the problem and popular algorithms.